# CloudConfigurationManager GetSetting - not getting value from cscfg when running in Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-cloud-services

We have a setting defined in our Azure Cloud Service (csdef)

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="CDN" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

And it's value in the cscfg file

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="CDN" value="az12345.vo.msecnd.net" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

And in order for to work "outside" of Azure we have this in the web.config

```
 <add key="CDN" value="localcdn" />
```

When the cloud service is deployed into Azure the value for CDN is "localcdn" and NOT the value that is in the cscfg file "az12345.vo.msecnd.net".

We have other cloud services with exactly the same setting which are resolved correctly, but this service refuses to.

My understanding from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager.getsetting.aspx is that it will get the value from the cscfg when in Azure and web/app.config when it's not.

We are using Microsoft Azure Configuration Manager 3.1.0

Comment: This is deployed as a cloud service, correct?  Also, have you verified the config setting in the Azure portal?

Comment: Yes, deploying it as a cloud service and the portal value what is in the cscfg.

Comment: It seems the role environment itself is throwing an exception, but Configuration Manager is just falling back silently to the web.config rather highlighting that there has been an exception in role.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue caused by Role Environment erroring